# BETTER query and faster

Tags: mysql

i would like to ask between these two query, what query is faster? if the data is 20k to 100k..

```
SELECT SUM(price * quantity) as sales
FROM
(
  SELECT price, quantity, date
  FROM orderline
  UNION ALL
  SELECT price, quantity, date
  FROM creditorderline
)
WHERE date BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2016-01-01'
```

OR

```
SELECT SUM(price * quantity) as sales
FROM
(
  SELECT price, quantity, date
  FROM orderline
  WHERE date BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2016-01-01'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT price, quantity, date
  FROM creditorderline
 WHERE date BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2016-01-01'
)
```

Comment: Try benchmarking it : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_benchmark

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because he should the benchmark by himself

Comment: Both of those options look disastrous in terms of performance, in comparison with some other options. There could be some significant performance differences between the two forms, depending primarily on how selective that date range predicate is (the number of rows that satisfy the conditions. My answer gives some insight on the differences, and gives an example query with a much "better" query pattern.

Comment: I'm not good with query, i know all this people that commented knows more. if you wanted to help, you can just suggest better query to help me rather than that. anyway. i already follow spencer query..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That second form may perform better for two possible reasons:

Predicates in the outer query aren't pushed into the inline view. So the query that has predicates within the inline view (i.e. the conditions in the `WHERE` clause on the query of the table) has potential to materialize a *derived table* that is significantly smaller than the first query.

With the predicates on the queries of the individual tables (the SELECT statements inside the parens), MySQL may be able to make use of an efficient range scan operation, if an appropriate index is available.

Given the large range of date values (5 years), I'm guessing that a very large percentage of rows in the tables satisfies the conditions. And that means you may not notice much difference between the two proposed queries.

---

To see a significant difference in performance between the two queries, there's a couple of conditions that would need to be met:

1) the number of rows that satisfy the condition(s) in the WHERE clause would need to be a significantly smaller set than all of the rows in the tables

2) indexes on each table that have `date` as the first column.

**Pattern for a "better query and faster"**

If what you're looking for is "better" performance, then use a query like this:

```
SELECT SUM(s.sales) AS sales
  FROM ( SELECT SUM(o.price * o.quantity) AS sales 
           FROM orderline o
          WHERE o.date BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2016-01-01'
          UNION ALL
         SELECT SUM(c.price * c.quantity) AS sales
           FROM creditorderline c
          WHERE c.date BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2016-01-01'
       ) s
```

Each of the SELECT within the inline view are going to return a single row, which is likely to be much smaller than either of the query options OP offered.

Given the large range of date (five years), I suspect that's a very large percentage of the rows in the table, so an index isn't likely to help much. If those predicates are more selective, pulling a small subset of the rows in the table, appropriate indexes may improve performance.

```
  ... ON orderline (date,price,quantity)  
  ... ON creditorderonline (date,price,quantity)
```

Comment: sorry for late reply. i was in a hurry when i saw your post. i already change my code similar to yours after realizing that the first query will load all item after filtering it.. thank you for explaining it.

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on indexing. Why not test indexing date field in both orderline and creditorderline tables first. As others have suggested, this will give you the best answer.